# ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth not working Asus fx503vd

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, asus

On my first install with ubuntu on this machine bluetooth was working fine. I did a new install once through a server method and this time from USB. Both time, which are the last two times, the Bluetooth is not working anymore. By devices it is just spinning really fast, it does seem to see two devices but not my headphones, when i try to connect to any device i just get the not set up.